# push is not working in AngularJS routing

Tags: angularjs, routes, push

I have a table of elements which I am using. When the button "Adauga la meniu" is clicked I want that element's details to be stored in an array of objects called currentMenu and displayed on addtomenu.html view.

addtomenu.html

```
<h3>My menu</h3>
      <table>
        <tr>
          <th>Aliment</th>
          <th>Calorii</th>
          <th>Proteine</th>
          <th>Lipide</th>
          <th>Carbohidrati</th>
          <th>Fibre</th>
        </tr>
        <tr ng-repeat="app in currentMenu">
          <td>{{ app.name }}</td>
          <td>{{ app.calorii }}</td>
          <td>{{ app.proteine }}</td>
          <td>{{ app.lipide }}</td>
          <td>{{ app.carbohidrati }}</td>
          <td>{{ app.fibre }}</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
<a href="#/tabel">Back to table</a>
```

some of app.js

```
app.config(function($routeProvider){
          $routeProvider
            .when("/tabel",{
               templateUrl: "tabel.html",
                          controller: "HomeController"
               })
            .when("/addtomenu",{
                          templateUrl: "addtomenu.html",
                          controller: "HomeController"
              })
                 });
```

some of HomeController

```
 $scope.currentMenu = [
                      {
                        name: '',
                        calorii: '',
                        proteine: '',
                        lipide: '',
                        carbohidrati:'' ,
                        fibre:  ''
                      }
                    ];
```

my add to menu function

```
$scope.addItem = function (product){
                    alert("OK");
                    $scope.currentMenu.push({name: product.name, calorii: product.calorii, proteine: product.proteine, lipide: product.lipide, carbohidrati: product.carbohidrati, fibre: product.fibre});
                    window.location = '#/addtomenu';
                };
```

function addItem will be called here:

```
tr ng-repeat="product in produse.products | orderBy:predicate:reverse | filter:query">
          <td class="left">{{ product.name }}</td>
          <td>{{ product.calorii }}</td>
          <td>{{ product.proteine }}</td>
          <td>{{ product.lipide }}</td>
          <td>{{ product.carbohidrati }}</td>
          <td>{{ product.fibre }}</td>
          <td><button ng-click="$parent.removeItem(product)" class="buttonimage"><img src="images/remove.png"/></button></td>
          <td><button ng-click="$parent.addItem(product)" class="buttonimage"><img src="images/addtomenu.png"/></button></td>
      </tr>
```

Full plunker here: https://plnkr.co/edit/HyXt7hWGtle1gWrv1U42?p=preview

I hope you will make me understand what is wrong, thanks for help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your adding function is off, I think. I'm fairly new to all this myself, but try this first:

Basically, you're trying to push an array into an array of the same name. Which probably creates some kind of screw-up. Try naming your newly added dish something else. Like this:

```
var myDish = [
                      {
                        name: '',
                        calorii: '',
                        proteine: '',
                        lipide: '',
                        carbohidrati:'' ,
                        fibre:  ''
                      }
                    ];
```

`currentMenu` remains to be the array of all dishes.

Then, I would advise you to use a numeric ID before you try to build an array. While not directly necessary, I understand that this is best practise. Use this line in your function to get an ID:

$scope.myDish.id = $scope.currentMenu.length + 1;

So your entire function would look like this:

```
    $scope.addItem = function () {
    $scope.myDish.id = $scope.currentMenu.length + 1;
        $scope.currentMenus.push({
            id: $scope.myDish.id
        }, $scope.myDish);

        yourService.yourFunctiontoGetArray().update($scope.myDish);
        $scope.myForm.$setPristine();
        $scope.myDish = {
                            name: '',
                            calorii: '',
                            proteine: '',
                            lipide: '',
                            carbohidrati:'' ,
                            fibre:  ''
                          };
    };
```

To make this work, you need to add to your `services.js` a function that accesses the database. I have used a version of the following in a previous project of mine:

```
.service('yourService', ['$resource', 'baseURL', function ($resource, baseURL) {

    this.yourFunctiontoGetArray = function () {
        return $resource(baseURL + "menu/:id", null, {
            'update': {
                method: 'POST'
            }
        });
    };
```

Notes: `baseURL` leads to where the database is stored. Like "127.0.01/db.json". And of course, you'd need to integrate `resource`into your project.

Good luck!

Comment: It makes sense to me now. I will try to implement and optymyze my function. Thanks for leading me to the right way!